# Linq if list null return null

Tags: linq, if-statement

I need a way to add if the `BeveragesList!= null` to field the model, but if is null to set `BeverageList = null`.

I try something like this:

```
 BeveragesList = su.Wine != null ? new List<BeverageModel>() 
 {
     new BeverageModel()
     {
         Name = su.Wine.name,
         ShortName =  su.Wine.shortName,
         Price =  su.Wine.price,
         Description = su.Wine.description,
         AlcoholContent = su.Wine.alcoholContent,
         Region =  su.Wine.Region.name,
         WineCaste =  su.Wine.wineCaste,
         UrlImageList = f.Select(i => _url+i.Image.urlImage).ToList(),
    }
}: null
```

I'm always getting an error, I try a lot of things. Soz for beeing newbieee.

Comment: Never return null when a collection is required, return an empty collection.

Comment: What kind of error message?

Comment: Maciej Los NotSupportedException: The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect' that error, I'm working with JSON.

Comment: Jeff, What you mean?  To send the all the model empty?

Comment: I don't see a query in your sample code. Or any LINQ. Jeff means instead of `null` you should return `new List<BeverageModel>() { }`, i.e. an empty list of `BeverageModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically problem looks like in selecting data not in if statement or ternary operator
Give a try to avoid below:

```
AlcoholContent = su.Wine.alcoholContent,
         Region =  su.Wine.Region.name,
```

And give a try to below instead:

```
your query
...
select new {
Su = su,
Wine = su.Wine,
Region = su.Wine.Region
}
```

Then do the selection as you wanted above like below:

```
 new BeverageModel()
 {
     Name = Wine.name,
     ...
```